# Only toggle one menu/ul item Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to write a program that parses a json and creates a ul li dashboard. I have gotten it to work where it displays the a screenname with its subscreen names by looping through. When the parent screen name is clicked, it toggles between displayed the subscreen names. However, I want it to only toggle one of the subscreen names at a time. Right now, when I click on two unopened parent screennames, both of them open. I've been trying to put a counter and keeping track but I'm new to jquery and don't know how to go about it. Here is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>


    <body>
       <div class="container">
            <div id="menu" class="list"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
  $(function() {
  
    function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        var li = $(ul).append(
          '<li>' + menu[i].screenName + '</li>');
        if (menu[i].subScreen != null) {
          var subul = $('<ul class="list"></ul>');
          $(li).append(subul);
          parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].subScreen);
        }
      }
    }
  
    var menu = $('#menu');
    parseMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
  });
  
  
  
  $(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
  });
```

Here is my json:

```
var JSON = {
    menu : [ {
        screenName : 'Title',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Enclosure1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure3',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    },{
        screenName : 'Link',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    },{
        screenName : 'Content',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    },{
        screenName : 'Enclosures',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Enclosure1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure3',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    }, {
        screenName : 'Authors',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Author1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Author2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    },{
        screenName : 'Published At',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    }, {
        screenName : 'Stream',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'STR1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'STR2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

I want the javascript to act in a way where if an unopened screen name is clicked the other opened screen name with their respective subscreen names shud be closed before the newly clicked screen names are opened. Thanks!

Comment: hi, any reason you are not using one of the many accordion implementations in the JS world?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to go about it using jquery. Would accordian help with this?

Comment: according to what I think you are trying to do, yes, any JS-based accordion will help and will be a lot better than doing it _by hand_

Comment: I'll look into it but I'd like to see if there's a solution using jquery if possible. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#content

Answer (score 0):

By using `$(this).next('ul').toggle()`, you're affecting *all* the next `<ul>` elements. In this case you want to toggle only the child elements, try using this instead: `$(this).children('ul').toggle();`

Comment: if I replaced next with children, the toggle doesn't work and nothing happens when I click. Is there something else I need to change in my function also?

Comment: I've created a pen and it seems to be working like that: https://codepen.io/ymf/pen/GRZyZVv

Comment: I wanted it in such a way where the other ul items get closed if I click on an unopened ul item.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide everything before you toggle the view of the selected element:

```js
$(function() {
  
    function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        var li = $(ul).append(
          '<li>' + menu[i].screenName + '</li>');
        if (menu[i].subScreen != null) {
          var subul = $('<ul class="list"></ul>');
          $(li).append(subul);
          parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].subScreen);
        }
      }
    }
  
    var menu = $('#menu');
    parseMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
  });
  
  
  
  $(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function() {
//        $('ul').hide(); // hide all ul when click 
    $('ul').not($(this).next('ul')).hide(); //hide all but the selected one
    $(this).next('ul').toggle(); // toggle view of selected one
  });



var JSON = {
    menu : [ {
        screenName : 'Title',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Enclosure1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure3',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    },{
        screenName : 'Link',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    },{
        screenName : 'Content',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    },{
        screenName : 'Enclosures',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Enclosure1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Enclosure3',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    }, {
        screenName : 'Authors',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'Author1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'Author2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    },{
        screenName : 'Published At',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : null
    }, {
        screenName : 'Stream',
        link : '#',
        subScreen : [ {
            screenName : 'STR1',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        }, {
            screenName : 'STR2',
            link : '#',
            subScreen : null
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">




       <div class="container">
            <div id="menu" class="list"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. The only problem is if I want to close something by clicking it twice (open and then close), The closing does not work. Do you know what can be done to fix that?

Comment: You can use `not` like this:  `$('ul').not($(this).next('ul')).hide();`

Comment: @HariKrishnaSenthilkumar i edited the above snippet. By the way like your approach of doing it by yourself. Since you already use bootstrap you can make your life easier with the native accordion: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example